# Cannot compile my document

Tags: compiling

I just installed TeX Live in a Linux Manjaro system through its package manager. I also use TeXstudio as a LaTeX editor. When I try to compile my document I get the following error

> /usr/bin/lualatex: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libpoppler.so.66: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory

This problem appears with both `xelatex` and `pdflatex` engine, respectively.

What does this problem mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: poppler is PDF rendering library, i.e. provides code to display PDF documents (in short). You must install the relevant libraries -- I don't know Manjaro, but I assume that there is a specific `poppler` or `libpoppler` package which contains the missing files

Comment: the problem was that `libpoppler` was missing, even though `poppler` was installed. Thus, i installed it by using `yaourt libpoppler` command

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- I think you nailed it.

Comment: @jon: Yes, probably, but not worth to transform the 'assumption' into an answer, in my point of view

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- Well, I certainly don't pay careful attention to the boundaries of what is an 'on-site' question, but doesn't that mean people should be voting to close it? If not, why not simply post your comment as an answer (and mark it as CW so someone else can 'improve' the answer later if they like)? Or the OP can post her/his own answer.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Close as OT due to bad installation or something, or add an answer?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: I think closing is better -- I don't believe I can add some really useful in an answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was caused by a failed/incomplete installation